# Where to find the version information in source code on Android platform

Tags: android

Where do I find the version information in source files on Android platform?

I tried to find out some information listed in setting >> about phone. Some of the displayed information is, firmware version, module number, baseband version, kernel version, ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can give it check in `platform\build\core\version_defaults.mk`

Comment: You can search the string "PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION" in above file to find the exact API version.

Answer (score 3):

For cyanogen, the source for this file is https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/cm-10.2/src/com/android/settings/DeviceInfoSettings.java , it looks like https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/DeviceInfoSettings.java is the equivalent in AOSP.

From those files, it looks like most of those values are constants or in the preferences, while the kernel is read from `/proc/version`.

Comment: What is these two files' purpose?
./build/tools/buildinfo.sh
./build/core/Makefile

Comment: Those aren't in the settings app, you should you don't mean that to be a separate question? Makefile at least is the instructions for building (or cleaning, or testing, or whatever. Makefiles can be programmed to run any kind of commands, but they are normally instructions for compiling).

Answer (score 1):

First, the android kernel source code is divided from the main android source code.

The `Android version` is the build version. It is found in `build/make/core/build_id.mk` in the aosp android source (https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading).

The `Kernel version` is in the top level `Makefile` of the android kernel source code (https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels-deprecated)